# How to repair a faucet leaking when tap is turned on...?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet

I have a bathroom faucet (Pegler) with separate hot and cold taps. When I turn on one of the taps water starts slowly leaking out around the base of the tap. The faucets work fine, and there's no leaking when turned off.
I tried opening the tap and replacing the O ring on the cartridge inside; I even put a bigger ring on, which seemed to work at first but now after about 10 secs it's still leaking.
Do I need a new cartridge or is there anything else I could try?
Thanks for any help!
Alan

Comment: O rings need to be the correct size to seal. If you installed a fatter o ring larger cross sectional size in some cases it may work but many times it will not create a proper mechanical seal. A larger diameter of the same cross sectional size will almost never work.

Comment: You say separate hot and cold taps , but mention cartridge.  You have a single valve but two spouts ? Do you have a picture of the unit or a model of the unit ? If it is only leaking when water is turned on then the cartridge itself and everything after it is suspect. Please post a picture of the unit or provide a model